# What happens to a Summoner's Eidolon if it is Petrified?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

What happens to a Summoner's Eidolon if it is Petrified?  Does it return at the beginning of the next day as if it were killed, or must it be freed of its effect first?

Comment: Though I don't have the book in front of me, I believe the spell Purified Calling will purge the eidolon of conditions such as petrification if you dismiss and resummon using this spell.

Answer (score 11):

A petrified character is considered unconscious, not dead. To restore the Eidolon back from being petrified, it would need to have the process reversed somehow. Destroying the petrified Eidolon utterly might enable the Summoner to call it back as if it had died.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Petrified

Comment: Ehh, the Eidolon is a statue at that point. Even shattering it at that point wouldn't kill the eidolon, it would need to have Stone to Flesh cast on it first. (Casting it on the pieces would be an effective way of killing it though)

Comment: That's true. Re-reading the petrified condition, damage to the creature doesn't occur until it's restored to living condition.

Answer (score 4):

According to the rules:

> Eidolons are **treated as summoned creatures**, except that they are not sent back to their home plane until reduced to a number of negative hit points equal to or greater than their Constitution score.
>
> ...
>
> **The eidolon remains until dismissed by the summoner (a standard action)**. If the eidolon is sent back to its home plane due to death, it cannot be summoned again until the following day.

According to the rules on summoning (emphasis mine)...

> Summoning: a summoning spell instantly brings a creature or object to a place you designate. When the spell ends or is dispelled, a summoned creature is instantly sent back to where it came from, but a summoned object is not sent back unless the spell description specifically indicates this. A summoned creature also goes away if it is killed or if its hit points drop to 0 or lower, **but it is not really dead. It takes 24 hours for the creature to reform**, during which time it can't be summoned again.

Because the summoned creature is being reformed on the current plane, I would argue that when an eidolon is petrified, it can be dismissed, and resummoned (incurring the normal one minute penalty to cast the ritual to summon it).

I recall there being some better explanation of how summoned creatures work, but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

Comment: You're missing the small bit in there: "The eidolon does not heal naturally." Which means it would still be a statue, would still have any damage it incurred, including attribute damage.

Comment: @Cthos, now that would be funny. You dismiss that statue and summon the eidolon back... as a statue. After all, it's still considered alive in that state, right?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly this is not covered by the rules and Paizo has thoroughly refused to say anything on the various forum posts asking about persistent effects and eidolons.  So all answers on this are opinions. The way they've explained eidolons is in a weird grey area between really being a persistent creature like an animal companion and being a completely ephemeral creature like a summon.

I personally rule that you can rid your eidolon of persistent effects by dismissing them for the full day, as if they had been killed. It seems to be a happy medium between having to limp around with a gimpy eidolon and continually pay extra money to get it clerical help, and letting such effects be couple-round inconveniences.

Answer (score -6):

I can't recall the source of my information, and admittedly can't be bothered to hunt it down right now, but I can say for sure this is what happens.
The summoner becomes unable to magically or naturally sleep or fall unconscious, but can still die. The eidolon can't be forcibly returned to it's home plane in this condition, even through banishment or dismissal. The summoner will gain fatigue and exhaustion as days pass, be unable to rest to recover spells per day, and lose all abilities requiring the eidolon. As the eidolon is remained forcibly summoned, the summoner also can't use their summon monster ability.
It's nearly as detrimental to a summoner as it is to a player who GETS petrified.

Comment: Sorry but without a source this answer may as well not exist.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, we kinda like sourced answers here, "I think I remember something" doesn't really help the poster to get a convincing answer.